# D3 and color grid

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, gridview, grid

I have a huge text file, which name is "tempanomaly_new.txt", and i have 1670 nombers of 2D arrays with size of 180*90. i read the text file and save the values in myMatrix.
    after that i tried to create a grid for one of my arrays,180*90, and i want read the value from myMatrix and save in gridData array for coloring my grid with these values. But i have big problem, because when i execute my code, it takes too much time and not show me any result. I am a beginner in javascript and d3.js and I hope you can help me.
    In addition, i read so many links such as https://bl.ocks.org/cagrimmett/07f8c8daea00946b9e704e3efcbd5739 and others, also in stackoverflow but i did not find anything.

here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
  <div id="grid"></div>

  <script>
    //creat 1670 numbers of matrices with size of 180*90
    var myMatrix = new Array(1670)
    for (var i = 0; i < 1670; i++) {
      myMatrix[i] = twodmatrix()
    }

    function twodmatrix() {
      var myMat = new Array(180)
      for (var i = 0; i < 180; i++) {
        myMat[i] = new Array(90)
      }
      return (myMat)
    }

    //read from file

    d3.text("tempanomaly_new.txt", function(data) {
      myMatrix = data
    })




    // save the values of one matrix in color matrix


    const NUM_COLOR = 16200;

    var colorArr = new Array(NUM_COLOR);
    for (var i = 0; i < NUM_COLOR; i++) {
      colorArr[i] = getColor();

    }

    function getColor() {
      color = "#" + [Math.floor(Math.values(myMatrix) * 16)];
      return color;
    }

    const BLOCK_SIZE = 30;
    const BLOCK_SPACE = 5;
    var gridData = new Array(180)
    for (var i = 0; i < 180; i++) {
      gridData[i] = new Array(90)
      for (var j = 0; j < 90; j++) {
        gridData[i][j] = {
          x: (i + 1) * BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SPACE,
          y: (j + 1) * BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SPACE,
          size: BLOCK_SIZE,
          color: colorArr[(i * 10 + j) % NUM_COLOR]
        }

      }
    }

    var grid = d3.select("#grid")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%")
      .style("color", "#b2b2b2");


    var row = grid.selectAll(".row")
      .data(gridData)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "row");


    var column = row.selectAll(".square")
      .data(function(data) {
        return data;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "square")
      .attr("x", function(data) {
        return data.x;
      })
      .attr("y", function(data) {
        return data.y;
      })
      .attr("width", function(data) {
        return data.size;
      })
      .attr("height", function(data) {
        return data.size;
      })
      .style("fill", function(data) {
        return data.color;
      })
      .style("stroke", "#222");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I do not have any result, and my program take too much time like stuck in a loop

Comment: i must comment that : color = "#"+[math.floor(myMatrix)].tostring(16)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
  <div id="grid"></div>

  <script>
    //create 1670 numbers of matrices with size of 180*90
    
    var myMatrix = new Array(1670)
    for (var i=0; i<1670; i++){
        myMatrix[i] = twodmatrix()
    }
  
    function twodmatrix(){
        var myMat = new Array(180)
        for (var i=0; i<180; i++){
            myMat[i] = new Array(90)
        }
        return(myMat)
    } 
    
    
    const NUM_COLOR = 16200;

    var colorArr = new Array(NUM_COLOR);
    for (var i = 0; i < NUM_COLOR; i++) {
      colorArr[i] = getColor();

    }

    d3.text("tempanomaly_new.txt", function(data){ myMatrix = data })
    function getColor() {
      color = "#"+[Math.floor(myMatrix)].toString(16); 
   // Math.values is not a function, myMatrix is empty array cause of missing file
      return color;
    }

    const BLOCK_SIZE = 30;
    const BLOCK_SPACE = 5;
    var gridData = new Array(180)
    for (var i = 0; i < 180; i++) {
      gridData[i] = new Array(90)
      for (var j = 0; j < 90; j++) {
        gridData[i][j] = {
          x: (i + 1) * BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SPACE,
          y: (j + 1) * BLOCK_SIZE + BLOCK_SPACE,
          size: BLOCK_SIZE,
          color: colorArr[(i * 10 + j) % NUM_COLOR]
        }

      }
    }

    var grid = d3.select("#grid")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", "5500px")
      .attr("height", "3000px")
      .style("color", "#b2b2b2");


    var row = grid.selectAll(".row")
      .data(gridData)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "row");


    var column = row.selectAll(".square")
      .data(function(data) {
        return data;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "square")
      .attr("x", function(data) {
        return data.x;
      })
      .attr("y", function(data) {
        return data.y;
      })
      .attr("width", function(data) {
        return data.size;
      })
      .attr("height", function(data) {
        return data.size;
      })
      .style("fill", function(data) {
        return data.color;
      })
      .style("stroke", "#222");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

1. Math.values isn't a function.
2. d3.text(file, function(data) {
      myMatrix = data;
   }, are you sure it is working ?

Comment: yes, I am sure. because when i wrote console.log(myMatrix), I can  see the values of my text file in myMatrix

Comment: and for the first question, i was deleted but because of my mistake some parts of my code were deleted and replaced with other codes.now i correct them but my problem does not solved